# If $f : [0, 1] → [0, 1]$ is a continuous function, then show that there exists some $c ∈ [0, 1]$ such that $f(c) = c^n$ , for a fixed $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

> If $f : [0, 1] → [0, 1]$ is a continuous function, then show that there exists some $c ∈ [0, 1]$ such that $f(c) = c^n$ , for a fixed $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. Kindly note that you have to present your working to attract solutions that may benefit you and the community. Also, you may refer to the Mathjax tutorial for typesetting the question in a way that is legible to everyone and follows a specified standard by the community.

Comment: "fixed" sounds confusing here.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x^n$, $g(0)=f(0)\geq 0$, $g(1)=f(1)-1\leq 0$

IVT implies there exists $c:g(c)=0$, we deduce that $f(c)=c^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x^{n}$. Then $g(0)=f(0)-0\geq 0$  and $g(1) =f(1)-1\leq 0$. By IVP of the continuous function $f$ there exists $c$ such that $g(c)=0$.